# How does increased capacitance in the audio path affect bass response in a power amplifier circuit?

Tags: amplifier, power-amplifier

I was reading an article about the well known JLH 1969 class A amplifier.  The author claims that increasing the capacitor values has improved the bass response. I'm looking to understand how this works. Why bypass all electrolytics with a low value polypropylene capacitor?

Original schematic from the article below, link to [the article here.](https://sound-au.com/tcaas/jlhesl.htm)

[image]

Comment: Please list the reference designators (C...) for the caps so we don't have to dig through the article.

Comment: Hello @Mattman944, According to the article it's all of the 470u capacitors in the schematic (pervious values were 220u)

Comment: In general, there are fixed resistances around any given capacitor, so making the capacitor larger makes the associated time constants longer, reducing the effective cutoff frequency.  If that cutoff frequency is associated with a high-pass filter (interstage coupling, emitter bypass, etc.), it gives you an extended range at the low end of the system response.

Comment: thanks Dave, what about bypassing electrolytics with polypropylene whats the reasoning behind that.

Comment: Large value electrolytics generally have poor high-frequency characteristics -- the impedance isn't as low as you'd like. Shunting with a film or ceramic capacitor gives you the best of both worlds.

Comment: It is most likely the author used standard alum electrolytic caps designed for 50/60 Hz rectifiers with poorer  Dissipation Factor (DF) or loss tangent or ESR than the original design based on low ESR caps. Only C1,and maybe C5,C6 improve the bass with low ESR & the others do not but affect high frequency block

Comment: Thanks, @TonyStewartEE75 So if a low ESR capacitor is used then there is no need to bypass with a polypropylene?

Comment: Correct.  The low cutoff on the input is 7.5Hz for C1 for speakers that roll off at 50 Hz this gives adequate low phase error at 50 Hz compared to circuit input impedance of 47k the 2.2uF is high impedance but should be film (which is non-polar) to avoid ceramic vibration noise and e-cap polar issues.

Comment: But it's hard or expensive to find 470uF PP caps  so smaller ones in parallel are fine.

Comment: Interesting, so switching all the electrolytes to PP would yield a better result? i found one but they are rare and expensive indeed. https://au.mouser.com/ProductDetail/EPCOS-TDK/B32320I4207K000?qs=ti9wR6LxNKX1Cjf2o3j7DQ%3D%3D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would assume the original design used high-quality low ESR e-caps which have "effective series resistance", ESR that is at least 10x lower than "standard" e-caps. ESR is similar to the measurement "Dissipation Factor"(DF) are only done for "standard" caps designed to run on 50/60 Hz rectifiers so always rated at 120 Hz.

- Polypropylene (PP) film caps have an ESR in the range of x mohms but would very large and more expensive in the >= 100 uF range.
- Aluminium electrolytic caps or e-caps ESR ranging for **100 uF from 44 mohms (lowest ESR) to 5 Ohms** then many "std" are not rated for ESR but rather use tan \$\delta\$ or DF) have an ESR*C=T = 100 to 300 us product in this range of C.  Low ESR caps might be T= 0.44us  to 50 us. and "std" e-caps are about 10x higher ESR loss.

This design has been modified to enhance the phase response on electrostatic speakers. We know that phase response extends a decade beyond the half power frequency response commonly used but 5x the break-point is an effective compromise.  The 7.5 Hz breakpoint input for DC blocking seems quite low for 50 Hz electrostatic speakers and might blow out a candle in front of a sub-woofer on power up. (lol)

C1 DC blocking cap  7.5Hz    RC=103 ms  film cap 2.2uF
C2 RF AM radio noise attenuation 180 KHz ceramic cap 330 pF
C3 Passband gain cut RC = 103 ms   low ESR 470 uF + film cap
C4 Booststrap cap output for signal to modulate the idle bias current T = 70.5 ms  low ESR 470 uF + film cap
C5, C6 supply boost peak current from LDO low ESR cap 100 uF + film cap

If you cannot find PP film caps in 470 uF which are rated for higher voltage than you need then get what you can 88 uF or 200 uF instead with low ESR Alum. electrolytic caps.

Std quality=2000h MTBF @ 80'C rating and high quality 20kh MTBF @ 105'C But there is a big range in price and size. Voltage add 25% margin.